# Is there a shortcut way to deploy angular 5 app to Azure without VSTS?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

If i build my angular 5 app locally, is there some was to 'publish to azure (web app)' directly instead of going through VSTS CI/CD pipeline?

I am using free VSTS account for test projects and want to save build time for production where i will use full blown CI/CD, but for testing and showcasing i'd like to go directly.

PS.
I am using angular CLI, not .net angular project templates.